# What's the most damage you can do in a single attack?

Tags: disgaea-4

What's the most damage a single attack could do (theoretically) with maxed out stats (level 9,999, relevant attack stat(s) at 9,999,999 points), beneficial item innocents, a max-level skill ect? I know anything that does even 1 billion damage will kill any enemy (normally) but I'm curious as to how high the numbers will go.

Is this something that can/has been calculated? I know I've seen the damage indicator go into the billions at least, so I also wonder if the max damage is capped at say 9,999,999,999 in one hit or if it's limited by the actual amount of damage feasable due to normal game mechanics.

Comment: I think once you hit billions of points of damage, it's essentially a moot point; everything should be dying in a single hit.  That said, I'd sort of be curious just how ludicrous Disgaea can get.  It's always been out being absolutely crazy.

Comment: @fbueckert yeah, the max for HP is below 1 billion (or it was in D3) but I'm curious as to how much damage you can actually do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This video seems to suggest the damage cap is 184.5 Quadrillilon:

Comment: Holy crap, sweet find! I never thought it went quite that high...

Comment: And thus, you see just how ludicrous Nippon Ichi is when it comes to Disgaea.  I can almost imagine some coder gleefully implementing a crazy high value, and seeing just how badly a PS3 blows up on it.

Comment: yes, nippon ichi always pushed the envelope with big numbers, which is awesome.  You dont' see many games that legitimately require bigints